# Function of a Markov chain is a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

Given a Markov chain $X_n$ with it's states taking values in the set $S$. $f$ is a function, $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If a $f(X_n)$ is also a Markov chain, prove that either $f$ is injective or $f$ is constant.  I'm totally clueless as to how I can proceed.

Comment: Perhaps try to come up with an example with $S = \{1,2,3\}$ and $f$ is not injective and not constant.

Comment: The idea I think they're getting at is that if $f(s_1) = f(s_2) = r$, then the transition probabilities out of $r$ depend on whether $r$ is "really" $s_1$ or $s_2$, and thus depend on the chain's history (which could be used to distinguish $s_1$ and $s_2$). Though it seems you could find counterexamples if $f$ "merges" states of the Markov chain with the same transition probabilities.

Answer (score 3):

The statement you're trying to prove is false.

For example, let $S =\{1,2,3\}$. Let $X_n$ be a Markov chain with transition matrix
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$
Let $f(x) = 1$ if $x=1$, and $2$ if $x \in \{2,3\}$. Then $f$ is neither injective nor constant, but $f(X_{n})$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & 0\\
      0 & 1\\
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$

The above example was not irreducible. Here's an irreducible example:
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$
We keep the same $f$. Then $f(X_{n})$ has transition matrix
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1/3 & 2/3\\
      1 & 0\\
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$

Here's a more complicated example:
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2/6 & 1/6 & 3/6 \\
      1/4 & 2/4 & 1/4 \\
      1/4 & 1/4 & 2/4
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$
Then $f(X_{n})$ has transition matrix
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1/3 & 2/3\\
      1/4 & 3/4\\
    \end{array}
  \right].
$$

As suggested in the second comment on the question, it's possible to merge states with the same outgoing probabilities, but in the last example, states 2 and 3 do not have the same outgoing probabilities. They only have the same outgoing probability to state 1.